# Facebook Live Comments API 400 Bad Request

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-live-api

I am trying to get a stream of comments from a live video.  Currently I am trying to use this as a guide:

https://developers.facebook.com/.../endpoints/live-comments

The problem is even if I don't use JavaScript and I just send the request with cURL and replace the video ID with the ID of the live video and put in either my user access token or I have also tried a page access token I just get back a 400 Bad Request.  I am using the exact same example from the link above and just replacing the required variables.

My request URL is this:

[https://streaming-graph.facebook.com/{liveID}/live_comments?access_token={accessToken}&comment_rate=one_per_two_seconds&fields=from{name,id},message`](https://streaming-graph.facebook.com/%7BliveID%7D/live_comments?access_token=%7BaccessToken%7D&comment_rate=one_per_two_seconds&fields=from%7Bname,id%7D,message%60)

except I remove the {} and replace them with the ID and the access token respectively.
At the bottom of the documentation it says a 400 error means I should check the URL and parameters are correct. Do you see anything wrong with the above URL? I have sent the request straight through cURL, through Postman, and also using EventSource like in the documentation and get a 400 Bad Request each time.

```
var source = new EventSource(
        `https://streaming-graph.facebook.com/{liveID}/live_comments?access_token={accessToken}&comment_rate=one_per_two_seconds&fields=from{name,id},message`)

    source.onmessage = function (event) {
        console.log(event)
    }

    source.onerror = function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }

    source.onopen = function (event) {
        console.log(event)
    }
```

The only one that fires from the above example is the `source.onerror` and I just get a 400 Bad Request.

I know my ID and Token are correct because if I use the graph API from here (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/live-video/comments/) to pull the comments it works, but that method wont give me a stream of comments as they come in it only gives whatever comments are there at the time of running the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright after some more testing I figured it out.  Turns out I was providing the "Post ID" to this and not the "Live ID" which was a different graph query.

Prior I was using:

[https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/{Page_Name}/posts](https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/%7BPage_Name%7D/posts)

and getting the ID from the post that contained the live video.  What I actually needed to do was:

[https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/{Page_Name}/live_videos](https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/%7BPage_Name%7D/live_videos)

This returns the correct ID to feed into the above live_comments endpoint.